# using virtual subdomains on nginx on localhost laragon server to be dynamic

Tags: nginx, php

i have this config file `domain.beta.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<version>(.+\.))?domain.beta$ domain.beta
    root "X:/xx/www/domain"

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex on;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php last;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

what i expect is these domains to work

```
domain.beta
www.domain.beta

v1.domain.beta
v2.domain.beta
...
www.v1.domain.beta
www.v2.domain.beta
...
```

but what works is only `domain.beta` and if i try anything else i get

```
www.domain.beta’s server IP address could not be found
v1.domain.beta’s server IP address could not be found
www.v1.domain.beta’s server IP address could not be found
```

my `nginx.conf` is

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    keepalive_timeout  32;
    proxy_connect_timeout  16000;
    proxy_send_timeout  16000;
    proxy_read_timeout  16000;
    send_timeout  16000;
    include "X:/xx/sites/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf";
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 32;
}
```

but i also want catch on it from php side as `$_GET['version']` but i could not reach that yet because stuck here

i just want it to work exactly as if it was rewrite like `domain.beta/v1/` but that does not help that `www.` does not work too

i have no background knowledge about manging servers except to rewrite urls